How to input dynamic value in whatsapp flow json?
I am trying to input dynamic value in whatsapp flow using json and gettin the following error.
{
  "version": "3.1",
  "screens": [
    {
      "id": "",
      "title": "Address",
      "data": {},
      "terminal": true,
      "layout": {
        "type": "SingleColumnLayout",
        "children": [
          {
            "type": "Form",
            "name": "flow_path",
            "children": [
              {
                "type": "TextInput",
                "name": "TextInput_23f9a3",
                "label": "Enter House Address",
                "required": true,
                "input-type": "text",
                "helper-text": "Please enter your house number, floor number and building number."
              },
              {
                "type": "TextBody",
                "text": "${data.area}",
                "visible": true
              },
              {
                "type": "TextBody",
                "text": "${data.pincode}",
                "visible": true
              },
              
              {
                "type": "Footer",
                "label": "Save Address",
                "on-click-action": {
                  "name": "complete",
                  "payload": {
                    "screen_0_TextInput_0": "${form.TextInput_23f9a3}"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

Error:
Missing dynamic data "${data.area}" in the data model for screen: screen_adtrrz, TextBody property: text.

Screenshot:
Error Screenshot
I tried implementing the static flow and it worked fine but the dynamic flow is giving an error.

The issue is that data.area is not present. The area needs to come from a previous screen.
Below is the example for this to help understand this
For Screen 1:
You have a form with two inputs
"children": [ { "type": "TextInput", "required": true, "label": "First name", "name": "first_name" }, { "type": "TextInput", "required": true, "label": "Last name", "name": "Last_Name" }
and the CTA is follows
{ "type": "Footer", "label": "Continue", "on-click-action": { "name": "navigate", "next": { "type": "screen", "name": "CONFIRMATION" }, "payload": { "name": "${form.first_name}", "second_name": "${form.Last_Name}" } } }
Screen 2:
"data": { "first_name": { "type": "string", "__example__": "Parth" }, "Last_Name": { "type": "string", "__example__": "Chawla" } }
And now you can use this
{ "type": "TextBody", "text": "${data.first_name}" }

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
